# Cannot retrieve the values of cookie in Smarty

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, smarty

I was working on a form where i get user's Name and Email to post a comment.  I was sending these data in a jquery ajax and in PHP file i am using this code to set a cookie.

```
            $strUserName    =   $_POST['strUserName'];
            $strEmail       =   $_POST['strEmail'];
        if ($_COOKIE["userNameCookie"] != $strUserName){
            setcookie("userNameCookie","",time()-3600);
        setcookie("userNameCookie", $strUserName,time()+60*60,"/domainName");}
        if ($_COOKIE["userEmailCookie"] != $strEmail){
            setcookie("userEmailCookie","",time()-3600);
        setcookie("userEmailCookie", $strEmail,time()+60*60,"/domainName");}
```

In Html i was getting the cookie value like this

```
<input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName"  value="{$smarty.cookies.userNameCookie}">
<input type="text" id="txtEmailQuest" name="txtEmailQuest" value="{$smarty.cookies.userEmailCookie}">
```

In Browser the cookie values are setting correctly.  But i cannot use this value in my HTML.  More over i need to use the same value of the cookies in other pages also.  How to set the cookie value in html and retrieve those values from cookie in other pages also.
Hope my Question is Clear.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Have you enabled cache in smarty?

Comment: Its already enabled.  We are using the same code to get values from cookies in other pages and its working fine.

Comment: You can try this plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie... very easy to use.

Comment: +1 Will try it.  Hope it will be useful for me in other requirement.  Though i am using smarty i am having tough time with cookies from Yesterday.

Comment: I don't know smarty but $_COOKIE only contains the Cookies submitted by the client. If you set it with setcookie because it was not set already it will not be aviable via $_COOKIE for that request. Only Futur request will contain it. If you want to Access your set cookie within the same reqeust you also need to set it in $_COOKIE

Comment: Thankyou @Rajiv007,  I tried and just edited my code and its working for me in smarty also.

Comment: You are welcome @Vignesh Gopalakrishnan. I have been using this plugin quite often.